# Unwrap li, and separate with commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to clone strings, unwrap `li`, and separate them with commas.

```
$('ul li div ul li').clone().prependTo('.ins');
```

```
<div style="display:none;">
<ul id="path">
  <li>
    <div class="wr_t">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#1">1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#2">2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#3">3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>  
  </li>
</ul>
</div>    
<div class="ins"></div>
```

I try to add `.unwrap('<li></li>')` before `.clone`, but it doesn't work.

I need to output `<a href="#1">1</a>,<a href="#2">2</a>,<a href="#3">3</a>`

Comment: Could you define the output you want?
Is it `<a href="#1">1</a>,<a href="#2">2</a>,<a href="#3">3</a>` you are after?

Comment: use $(".wr_t li").unwrap() instead

Comment: What has fiddle to your question? Or what is wrong with it? What result you are trying to have?

Comment: yes i need output <a href="#1">1</a>,<a href="#2">2</a>,<a href="#3">3</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qeQ6L/

```
$('.wr_t a').clone().prependTo('.ins').after(',');
```

You were going about it the wrong way, I targeted the links directly and cloned them before inserting them in .ins